# input type=number, allow values not rounded to step size

Tags: javascript, html

I've got some HTML input elements that are number input boxes. If I set a step="0.1", then inputs that are like 0.001 become invalid. If I set a step="0.001", then there's too much click involved.

This behavior seems to be enforced on Firefox 42, but Chrome 46 allows any number to be used. Here's an example, http://jsfiddle.net/1Lwe59yq/

```
<html>
  <input type="number" id="num" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" />
  <script>
    document.getElementById("num").value = 0.001;
  </script>
</html>
```

try it in Firefox then try it in Chrome for comparison.

How can I make the input boxes think all numbers are valid but still retain a step size for when the user clicks on the up or down arrows?

Caveat, no external libraries can be used in this project.

Thanks

EDIT: still no good solution here so I already implemented my own custom textboxes with validation and up/down buttons

Comment: Do you have to use an ´<input type=number>`? This sounds like it would make more sense to use a normal text input and use JavaScript to validate and format the value and add custom +/- buttons.

Comment: I like how it automatically gives you the numbers only keyboard on mobile across all platforms

Comment: This is sad, so many instances of this issue where we have to give up on standard HTML controls because the validation behavior is tied to the step size.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your 'step' needs to have the same amount of decimals as that value, but you can just set a placeholder like any other input
    http://jsfiddle.net/1Lwe59yq/1/

```
<input type="number" id="num" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" placeholder=".001" />
```

Comment: (and then make it the same color through CSS if you need to)

Comment: sorry, but I actually have JS calculations that will fill in those values, so this solution won't work. If the user changes this box, other boxes get calculated, if the user changes those other box, this box get calculated.

Comment: ahh got it @Frank26080115 – what if you set your value in JS like you are, and also set your step to that correct decimal place, then on the first change—in JS you can also set the step to the interval you want?